# How to make AppleScript ignore escape characters in string to make a Note

Tags: applescript, python, notes.app

I have a python script that takes a user's input and inserts it into the `name` and `body` parameter of the `make new note` apple script. The problem is that any escape or special characters get interpreted by applescript. I want all strings to be treated as raw and to ignore all escape characters and things like `:\//tft//` without giving me a `Expected “"” but found unknown token.` error

The line of python looks like this:

```
cmd = "osascript -e 'tell application \"Notes\" \n tell account \"iCloud\" \n make new note at folder \"Notes\" with properties {name:\"%s\", body:\"%s\"} \n end tell \n end tell'" % (header, body)
```

... where `header` and `body` are the user supplied strings.

But for manual testing I use the Script Editor to quickly reproduce the error.

```
tell application "Notes"
  tell account "iCloud"
    make new note at folder "Notes" with properties {name:"myname", body:"c:\test\test.txt"}
  end tell
end tell
```

This particular note ends up looking like this:

[image]

I know that I can use `\\` instead of `\` but I don't want users to have to sanitize all their input as they could be copy pasting from a large body of text. Think of a log file or paste-bin style body of text.

Is there a way to programmatically sanitize the user's input?